# Swift how change the background color and button border

Tags: ios, swift

I have function:

```
func setSelectedSystemButtonColor(hoverButton: Int){
    let defaultColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 62/255, blue: 132/255, alpha: 1)
    let selectedColor = UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 186/255, blue: 8/255, alpha: 1)

    homeBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    productsBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    calculatorBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    conceptBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    tipBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor

    if hoverButton == 1 {
        homeBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 2 {
        productsBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 3 {
        calculatorBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 4 {
        conceptBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 5 {
        tipBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
}
```

This function is designed to:
a) reset the color to default,
b) set the background color for the selected button + add a border.

The colors change correctly, however the borders do not display.
The borders would be on 5px

Comment: refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854469/change-uibutton-bordercolor-in-storyboard and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492740/button-border-with-transparent-background-in-swift

Comment: You have to set borderWidth too: `button.layer.borderWidth = 5`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162411/how-to-create-border-in-uibutton?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to set `UIButton` Border

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do it like:

```
  homeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 5
  homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
```

instead of simply doing:

```
  homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

Only Replace this line

```
let defaultColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 62.0/255.0, blue: 132.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

with

```
let selectedColor = UIColor(red: 251.0/255.0, green: 186.0/255.0, blue: 8.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show button border, first you have to explicitly give  `homeBtn` border width like this:

```
homeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
```

then only you can add color to `homeBtn` border layer like this:

```
homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset border width all buttons.

```
func setSelectedSystemButtonColor(hoverButton: Int){
    let defaultColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 62/255, blue: 132/255, alpha: 1)
    let selectedColor = UIColor(red: 251/255, green: 186/255, blue: 8/255, alpha: 1)

    homeBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    productsBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    calculatorBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    conceptBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor
    tipBtn.backgroundColor = defaultColor

    // reset border width of all buttons
    homeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    productsBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    calculatorBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    conceptBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
    tipBtn.layer.borderWidth = 0.0

    // set border width for selected button
    hoverButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    if hoverButton == 1 {
        homeBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 2 {
        productsBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 3 {
        calculatorBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 4 {
        conceptBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
    if hoverButton == 5 {
        tipBtn.backgroundColor = selectedColor
        homeBtn.layer.borderColor = defaultColor.cgColor
    }
}
```